# QList for touch-points not being created, "A data abort exception has occurred"

Tags: qt, qglwidget, qlist

I am trying to get touch inputs for my program targeting an N8 (and a C7), and I am not able to create a QList for keeping touchpoints using QTouchEvent::touchPoints(). The program crashes with the following line: `Thread has crashed: A data abort exception has occurred accessing 0xee`

The overloaded events function looks like:

```
bool GLWindow::event(QEvent *event)
{
    switch ( event->type() ) {
        case QEvent::TouchBegin: {
            QList<QTouchEvent::TouchPoint> touchBeginPoints =
                        static_cast<QTouchEvent *>(event)->touchPoints();
            foreach (const QTouchEvent::TouchPoint &touchBeginPoint, touchBeginPoints)
            {
                float touchBeginX = touchBeginPoint.pos().x();
                float touchBeginY = touchBeginPoint.pos().y();
                qDebug() << "touchBeginPoint := " << touchBeginX << ",  " << touchBeginY;
            }
            break;
        }
        case QEvent::TouchUpdate: {
            // same as touch begin: getting touch point
            break;
        }
        case QEvent::TouchEnd: {
            // same as touch begin: getting touch point
            break;
        }
        default: {
            qDebug() << "Goodbye";
           return true;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Now,

- I have never worked with containers before. But creating and using a QList in another part of the program works fine. Should I be including something in my .pro file? (Most problems seem to end up regarding this with me!)
- I read (a bit) about exceptions in Qt and Symbian, but I am not able to get most of that. BUT I am not doing any networking or resource based i/o or manipulation except textures for 3D objects. Is it possible that memory allocation while running the program is creating some problem?

Basically I am just trying to print the touch point. But I am clueless as to why I can’t create a QList. The code compiles fine. I tried my best (unsuccessfully), but is there any other way to get the screen coordinates of a touchpoint (one that does not require a QList)? Any comments are welcome.

[[Reposting](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/15585/) from [qt-project.org](http://qt-project.org).]

Comment: Just a hunch, but what happens if your replace static_cast<> with qobject_cast<> ?

Comment: @teukkam events are not objects... maybe dynamic_cast<>...

Comment: @teukkam It leads to an error: `no matching function for call to 'qobject_cast(QEvent*&)'`. I also tried dynamic_cast<>, it gives the same result. Thanks.

Comment: You're right @UmNyobe sorry about that mistake. The point was that if I remember correctly, data abort is Symbian's cryptic way of saying there's a null pointer (or some other arbitrary pointer) being dereferenced somewhere.

Comment: I am more and more confident that there's nothing that could cause that crash inside this code block. Did you try putting a qDebug at the top of the case block to see if it crashes already before creating your QList?

Comment: @teukkam I put qDebug(s) just before and after the line(s) creating the QList(s) for the touchPoints for touch begin, update and end etc., and the second one(s) never come to the console. It implies (to me) that the problem is only while creating the QList. I too am quite bugged with this happening, since I got this code idea from the Qt finger-paint and knobs examples, and it seems to work there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is 100% correct. Just look at this example: http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Painting_in_Qt

What I'm guessing happens is that `QTouchEvent::touchPoints()` returns a list big enough that it overflows your stack. Try increasing the stack size for your application.

Comment: Put qDebug() << static_cast<QTouchEvent *>(event)->touchPoints()->size() before the QList creation to see how big a list it will return

Comment: I put the qDebug statement as you said firstly inside the case for touch-begin where it crashed. Then I put it outside the switch and turns out the event function was called two times only: first time the size was `0` and second time it was `54065912`. Note that this was when I did not even touch the screen i.e. the event function being called during app startup/initialization. Then I tried the same with the fingerpainting example and the size for the touchPoints QList was 1 most of the time (and never more than 2 or 3), which reinforces your big-list argument.

Comment: Point is, even if I increase the stack size for my app, the QList is too big to let anything else take memory space. So I think I should somehow take care of its size (and not the app's stack size), but I can't since the thing crashes as soon as the list is created.

Comment: If you put it outside the switch, you are getting arbitrary results for random events that aren't even QTouchEvents. Besides, if your touch driver adaptation would be acting funnily and reporting ridiculous amounts of touch points, then you would be having problems in other applications as well. So I guess there goes that theory...

Comment: I tried getting the ('supposedly' touch) event values, and these are 2,3,4 or 5: all values for mouse events. +1 to you (+100 if I could since I could never find this error alone). Though the Qt examples are running fine with their touch events, I think I'll proceed with mouse events since all I need is the point of clicking on screen. But a click-point can give me just a single point, whereas a user may touch at more than a point. But I'll test this app on some friend's PC first, and then see what happens. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Is your syntax correct ? The compilation error seems to reinforce `teukkam` point...
What happens when you replace

```
  static_cast<QTouchEvent *>(event)->touchPoints()
```

With

```
  (dynamic_cast<QTouchEvent *>(event))->touchPoints()
```

Notice the parentheses...

Comment: No, `(dynamic_cast<QTouchEvent *>(event))->touchPoints()` has same result as static_cast<> or dynamic_cast<> without the parenthesis, a crash as soon as I touch the screen. Thanks.